# how to convert pandas time data into the format that can be processed by matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, dataformat

in the 3 section of lecture, i encounrtered a problem that I could not upload any finance data from yahoo, so I use pandas datareader to uploaded a stock info for microsoft here is that code:

```
MS= data.DataReader(name = "MSFT", data_source = "yahoo", start = "2007-07-
10", end = "2008-12-10")
MS.head()
```

I got this :
            Open         High      Low         Close      Adj Close   Volume
Date
2007-07-10  29.700001   29.990000   29.180000   29.330000   22.709541   66013500
2007-07-11  29.240000   29.650000   29.209999   29.490000   22.833429   48017000
2007-07-12  29.559999   30.110001   29.440001   30.070000   23.282511   54302400
2007-07-13  29.940001   30.020000   29.660000   29.820000   23.088938   42173000
2007-07-16  29.760000   30.240000   29.719999   30.030001   23.251535   4802320

I got a date frame and with a date column as a index 
when I plot it with .plot() it works

but how can i use plt.plot() to plot the pandas time data or how can i convert the format of pandas time data into readable format for matplotlib? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your `Date` column holds those date strings, try this:

```
MS['date'] = pd.to_datetime(MS['date'])
```